# Como carregar imagem de um JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro da minha div 'dados' carrego as informações do JS pelo id dentro dos spans, não estou conseguindo carregar a imagem dentro do span id='imgspan'

```
    <div class="dados">
       <label><span id="orderid"></span></label>
        <label><span id="endereco"></span></label>
        <label><span id="bairro"></span></label>
        <label>imagem: <span id="imgspan" /></label>
    </div>

$('#cities').change(function() {
      var orderid = values[$(this).val()].OrderID;    
      var endereco = values[$(this).val()].Endereco;
      var bairro = values[$(this).val()].Bairro;
      var imgspan= values[$(this).val()].ImgSpan;

      $('#orderid').text(orderid);
      $('#endereco').text(endereco);
      $('#bairro').text(bairro);
      $('#imgspan').text(imgspan)
    });
```

MEU JS

```
 var values = [
             {"OrderID": "Santo André",
              "Endereco": "Rua Bernardino de Campos, 171",
              "Bairro":"Centro",
              "ImgSpan":"<img src='../img/pointer.png' alt='' />"
              }]
```

Comment: `<span id="imgspan" />`... está errado a sintaxe.

Comment: Tente <div id="ImgSpan"></div>

Comment: Alias, sou seu vizinho de São Bernardo haha, tire também aquele "/ >" no fim do <img src, aquilo não é necessário.

Comment: Victor, não funcionou substituir o ID

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
          var values = [
         {"OrderID": "Santo André",
          "Endereco": "Rua Bernardino de Campos, 171",
          "Bairro":"Centro",
          }
         function image() {  
         var img = document.createElement("imgspan"<img src="../img/pointer.png">;  
         img.src = "../img/pointer.png"";  
         document.getElementById('imgspan').appendChild(img);  
         }]
```

E o code:

```
      <div class="dados">
      <label><span id="orderid"></span></label>
      <label><span id="endereco"></span></label>
    <label><span id="bairro"></span></label>
    <label>imagem: <div id="imgspan"></div></label>
</div>

   $('#cities').change(function() {
  var orderid = values[$(this).val()].OrderID;    
  var endereco = values[$(this).val()].Endereco;
  var bairro = values[$(this).val()].Bairro;
  var imgspan= values[$(this).val()].ImgSpan;

  $('#orderid').text(orderid);
  $('#endereco').text(endereco);
  $('#bairro').text(bairro);
  $('#imgspan').text(imgspan)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando:

```
<div class="dados">
       <label><span id="orderid"></span></label>
        <label><span id="endereco"></span></label>
        <label><span id="bairro"></span></label>
        <label>imagem: <span id="imgspan"></span> </label>
    </div>

$('#cities').change(function() {
      var orderid = values[$(this).val()].OrderID;    
      var endereco = values[$(this).val()].Endereco;
      var bairro = values[$(this).val()].Bairro;
      var imgspan= values[$(this).val()].ImgSpan;

      $('#orderid').text(orderid);
      $('#endereco').text(endereco);
      $('#bairro').text(bairro);
      $( '#imgspan' ).empty();
      $('#imgspan').append(imgspan);

    });
```

e no JS

```
 var values = [
             {"OrderID": "Santo André",
              "Endereco": "Rua Bernardino de Campos, 171",
              "Bairro":"Centro",
              "ImgSpan":"<img src='../img/pointer.png' alt='' />"
              }]
```

Comment: Desta forma o JS esvazia o campo 'imgspan', caso o empty não seja colocado o JS irá colocando um em sequência do outro a cada vez que o JS é chamado